# How to use a chunk delimiter in a raw data file?

Tags: java

I want to save raw data chunks to a file, And later on read those chunks one by one. This is no big deal except the following doubt:

What exact bytes to use as a delimiter, i.e to identify end of one chunk and beginning of next ? Given that chunk data might also contain such a sequence of bytes by random chance.

Notes: chunks are of variable size and contain random data. They are `jpeg` images actually.

Comment: If you use constant chunk size you don't need a delimiter. Otherwise you need to find a byte (or sequence of bytes) that will never be in your data.

Comment: That's the problem chunks are of variable size, and random data.

Comment: If your data can't contain two identical bytes next to each other, use that information as a variable delimiter. Other than that my only tip is one file per chunk.

Comment: it's the situations like this when we resort to using DB...  if it is an option

Comment: Also possible, but not very nice: use a very long delimiter (e.g. 256 bytes from `00000000` to `11111111`) and hope this bytes sequence will never occur. I wouldn't do it that way, though.

Comment: @foampile DB's also store blobs in a single file, they also pull this off somehow, I'm after that technique.

Comment: you could create a 2nd file in which you save the byteranges of your chunks in the chunkfile.

Comment: get the source code for MySQL and try debugging

Comment: @jlordo Nice idea, thanks. Also I can combine this byteranges data to fie header when all chunks are saved. This would result in a single file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first write the length of the chunk to the file as a fixed-size value, e.g. a 4 bytes integer, followed by the data itself:

```
public void appendChunk(byte[] data, File file) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true)));
        stream.writeInt(data.length);
        stream.write(data);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you later have to read the chunks back from that file, you start by reading the length of the first chunk. You now can decide whether to read the chunk data, or whether to skip it and continue with the next chunk.

```
public void processChunks(File file) throws IOException {
    DataInputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
        while (true) {
            try {
                int length = stream.readInt();
                byte[] data = new byte[length];
                stream.readFully(data);
                // todo: do something with the data
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                // end of file reached
                break;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also add other meta-data about the chunks, like writing the original name of the file with stream.writeUTF(...). You only have to make sure that you write and read the same data in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 2nd file in which you save the byteranges of your chunks in the chunkfile, or add that information to the header of your chunkfile. Did something similar once, don't forget that the byteranges than have the additional offset of the length of the header.

```
int startbyte = 0;
int lastByte = 0;
int chunkcount = 0;
File chunkfile;
File structurefile;
for (every chunk) {
    append chunk to chunkfile
    lastByte = startByte + chunk.sizeInBytes()
    append to structurefile: chunkcount startByte lastByte
    chunkcount++;
    startByte = lastByte + 1
}
```